# SQL Query Error SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql

here I have some problem during make database on mysql :

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'use android_api

> create table users(    id int(11) primary key auto_increme' at line 3

here my code :

```
create database android_api /** Creating Database **/
 
use android_api /** Selecting Database **/
 
create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

looking forward for your help. thanks

Comment: I think you have missed the semicolon at the end of create database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use semicolon ; at end of each statement.**

```
create database android_api; /** Creating Database **/

use android_api; /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolons.

While running SQL queried it is mandatory to add semicolons `;` at the end of each statement. You had semicolons at the end of `create table` statement but you missed it in `create database` and `use` statements.

```
create database android_api; /** Creating Database **/

use android_api; /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

For MySQL **error codes** and **messages** you can refer this [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

Already some people answer you question, with add on this:

> Semicolon ';'indicates end of a statement, so if there are multiple
>   statements then you should use semicolon else it will work fine.

So it is good practice to use whether it is single statement or multiple statements

```
create database android_api; /** Creating Database **/

use android_api; /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(



); /** Creating Users Table **/
```